# open-sourced LU decomposition and update

Tags: linear-programming, matrix-factorization

I am working on my own LP solver but with the module of LU decomposition and update missing. Just wondering if there are any open-sourced and widely used packages from github that I can use to merge into my developed LP framework.

Answer (score 0):

A solid and well-known implementation is LUSOL from Mike Saunders (Stanford). https://stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lusol/